# How to replace all string with dollar sign in html file?

Tags: javascript

I get html template as string from db and before i write file in node I want to replace all `${survey_url}` with number in this string. I tried with:

```
str.replace(/${survey_url}/g, params.orderId)
```

but it does not work. Could you help me understanding what's wrong?

Comment: $ and { and } are regular expression sign which have a special meaning. Does escaping helps you? /\$\{survey_url\}/g ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{`, `}` and `$` are a meaningful characters in a regular expression, so you'll need to escape them.

```
str.replace(/\$\{survey_url\}/g, params.orderId);
```

MDN has a good section on how [regular expressions work](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `$` and `{...}` are special characters, so they aren't interpreted literally.

Particularly:

- `$` means the end of a string
- `{...}` indicates a range

So you need to escape these characters:

```js
const output = '${greeting} user!'.replace(/\$\{greeting\}/g, 'hello');

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try escaping the `$` with a `\$`